# CKEditor лишние отступы и переносы строк

Tags: форматирование, html, ckeditor, разметка

Всем доброго дня.

Кто может поможет решить проблему. Заключается она в следующем:

Исходный код (в БД или написанный вручную) выглядит так: [alt text http://s017.radikal.ru/i405/1303/cb/39e2c7da3434.png](http://s017.radikal.ru/i405/1303/cb/39e2c7da3434.png)

Но только стоит переключиться в визуальный редактро и снова перейти в исходный код, так сразу все "слетает" и становится так: [image]

В результате чего, "копаться" в исходном коде становится ужасно неудобно. Уже что только не пробовал менять в config.js, но все безрезультатно. Может кто сталкивался с подобным и знает решение, буду весьма признателен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем решение нашел сам, хоть и "топорное", но все же. Если кому интересно в файле (ckeditor.js):

после строки

```
j.add('htmlwriter');
```

есть код:

```
$: function () {
        var o = this;
        o.base();
        o.indentationChars = '\t';
        o.selfClosingEnd = ' />';
        o.lineBreakChars = '\n';
        o.forceSimpleAmpersand = 0;
        o.sortAttributes = 1;
        o._.indent = 0;
        o._.indentation = '';
        o._.inPre = 0;
        o._.rules = {};
        var m = f;
        for (var n in e.extend({}, m.$nonBodyContent, m.$block, m.$listItem, m.$tableContent)) o.setRules(n, {
            indent: 1,
            breakBeforeOpen: 1,
            breakAfterOpen: 1,
            breakBeforeClose: !m[n]['#'],
            breakAfterClose: 1
        });
        o.setRules('br', {
            breakAfterOpen: 1
        });
        o.setRules('title', {
            indent: 0,
            breakAfterOpen: 0
        });
        o.setRules('style', {
            indent: 0,
            breakBeforeClose: 1
        });
        o.setRules('pre', {
            indent: 0
        });
    },
```

так вот в нем нужно изменить параметры в блоке:

```
o.setRules(n, {
    indent: 0,
    breakBeforeOpen: 1,
    breakAfterOpen: 0,
    breakBeforeClose: !m[n]['#'],
    breakAfterClose: 1
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, помогло решить проблему с добавлением тегов "<p></p>" после перехода в редактор исходного кода)