# Как избавиться от переносов после вставки кода из CKEditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

Никак не могу разобраться из-за чего при вставке кода (например пхп) из CKEditor, код отображается не совсем корректно. Появляются какие-то переносы. Скрин ниже.

[image]

Comment: Вообщем ситуация на данный момент такая-испытал всё на своём шаблоне в чистом виде(без лишних скриптов и т.д.)-всё работает...создалось впечатление что код "ломается" после того как попадает на страницу через БД из поля textarea...подскажите может кто сталкивался?

Comment: вопрос можно закрывать-последствия гав##кода...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [CKEditor лишние отступы и переносы строк](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198837/ckeditor-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CKEditor лишние отступы и переносы строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198837/html-ckeditor-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ -не помогло,все осталось как есть...да и проблема у человека совсем другая...